# Angular 8 multiple projects in one app — Project vs Library

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, project, angular8

We have a pretty big Angular 8 project with tens of thousands of lines of code. Now, we have one client that needs a bit of totally individual functionality — so we need to have the main system (that everyone gets), but optionally be able to include the client-specific code when running ng build for that specific client.

I've been going back and forth between projects and libraries and environment configurations and trying to find the best way...

Would the best approach be to move pretty much the entire existing code into a library ("ng generate library"), and then create 2 different projects ("ng generate project") that both use the shared library files? So project 1 is the main build for all clients, project 2 then contains just the bits of extra coding for this new client?

This seems like the wrong way to do it, but I really can't figure out an alternative approach.

Thanks in advance for any ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular project mono repo with NgRx state management and lazy-loading is really good solution for your problem. You can [read more about it here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/making-angular-project-mono-repo-with-ngrx-state-management-and-lazy-loading-3f09178319d4)

Answer (score 0):

@N.Tasikj answer above was helpful.

But what we ended up doing was this: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527.

It's not working perfectly yet, but I think we're on the right track.

Comment: It's almost same thing, but with monorepo you will have more control. There are a lot of commands who will help you to organize your apps, like creating graph of shared components, some format things...